# Regex with $ broken by positive lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Why this regex : `(§.)+$` https://regex101.com/r/4oMrcZ/1 is working as expected.

But this following regex doesn't match anything : `(§(?=.))+$` in `§f§fxx§f§dq§m§p` https://regex101.com/r/4oMrcZ/2

Thanks !

Comment: A lookahead does not consume the text its pattern matches, the index stays at the position where it was before trying the lookaround pattern.

Comment: You can find [this article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) interesting.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish but the lookahead in this case is meaningless.

Comment: The lookahead's goal is to don't catch the char after the §